# Why isn't my new class being picked up?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to change the class of a button so when its clicked, it hides a div, the text changes to show and the class is change using addClass/removeClass so it can be picked up by the next click event which will reverse the process.

However, its not quite working and im not sure why :/

Heres my code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vanishing Act</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="vanish1"></div>
        <div class="vanish2"></div>
        <div class="vanish3"></div>
        <div class="vanish4"></div>
        <br/>
        <br />
        <button class='first' value='button'>Hide the box!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.vanish1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F38630;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.hide1 {
    color: red;
}
```

JQ:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.first').click(function() {
            $('.vanish1').fadeOut('slow');
            $(this).text('Show the box!');
            $(this).addClass("hide1");
            $(this).removeClass("first");
    });

    $('.hide1').click(function() {
        $('.vanish1').fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).text('Hide the box!');
        $(this).removeClass("hide1");
        $(this).addClass("first");
    });
});
```

When I click the button, the div successfully hides and the class is changed (confirmed by the CSS and Chromes dev tools). But when I click it again, nothing happens..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into event delegation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when you change the html dynamically. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57xSR/).

```
$('body').on('click', '.first', function() {
        $('.vanish1').fadeOut('slow');
        $(this).text('Show the box!');
        $(this).addClass("hide1");
        $(this).removeClass("first");
});
$('body').on('click', '.hide1', function() {
    $('.vanish1').fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).text('Hide the box!');
    $(this).removeClass("hide1");
    $(this).addClass("first");
});
```

Comment: Note that `$('body')` is sub-optimal. I prefer `$(document.body)`. Note that normally one delegates to `$(document)` when not given a better parent.

Comment: Just so I understand the code. Is you initial call to the object that '.first' is contained in? Then the on method and so on.

Are there any videos that I can look at to get a better idea?

Comment: The format is $("parent").on('event', 'selector', function(){}); Watch this [youtube video](http://youtu.be/sE78APEbKbQ?t=12m28s) starting around 12:30min. It explains the performance enhancements to your code. Also go to this [article](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in the jquery documentation of the `.on()` method

Answer (score 0):

you are adding/removing class dynamically
means you are adding the class `hide1` when `.first` is clicked so prior to this click for the `.hide1` isn't registered

try binding the event to the body using jquery's on

Answer (score -1):

At the time of defining your handlers, the `.hide1` button doesn't exist yet and therefore it doesn't bind the event. There are two ways around this:

1: Use an actual toggle:

```
(function() {
    var toggle = true;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".first").click(function() {
            toggle = !toggle;
            if( toggle) {
                $(".vanish1").fadeIn("slow");
                $(this).text("Hide the box!").removeClass("hide1").addClass("first");
            }
            else {
                $(".vanish1").fadeOut("slow");
                $(this).text("Show the box!").addClass("hide1").removeClass("first");
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

or 2: use `on`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.first').on('click',function() {
            $('.vanish1').fadeOut('slow');
            $(this).text('Show the box!').addClass("hide1").removeClass("first");
    });

    $('.hide1').on('click',function() {
        $('.vanish1').fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).text('Hide the box!').removeClass("hide1").addClass("first");
    });
});
```

Method 1 is preferred.

Comment: Method 2 won't bind anything either. Are you confusing `on` with `live`?

Comment: Probably. Non-jQuery user here, just using what I've picked up around SO.

Comment: The proper syntax to delegate with `on` is `$(document).on('click', '.hide1', function(){...})`. Replace `document` with the closest parent that you can bind to.